# AVAssetExportSession in share extension

Tags: ios, avassetexportsession

I'm trying to use AVAssetExportSession on video selected in share extension and getting

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-3000 "Cannot create file"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create file,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x14811fdb0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-12124 "(null)"}}

But I can create file manually at the same NSURL without an error. Here is a function I'm using

```
func reencodeVideo() {
    let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: video.url)

    let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as AVAssetTrack
    print(videoTrack.estimatedDataRate)
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: videoAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080)
    guard let outputURL = uploadableFileURL else {
        return
    }
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    // let created = fileManager.createFileAtPath(outputURL.path!, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    if let path = outputURL.path where fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) {
        print("file exists")
    }
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItemAtURL(outputURL)
        print("deleted")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL
    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

    exportSession?.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler{
        print(exportSession?.status)
    }
}

private var uploadableFileURL: NSURL? {
    guard let tempFileName = video.url.lastPathComponent else {
        return nil
    }
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    guard let containerURL = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(Constants.appGroupIdentifier) else {
        return nil
    }
    return containerURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("videoFile.mov")
}
```

I've successfully created file in the same directory, but AVAssetExportSession returns an error there. 
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried using `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter`, and `AVAssetWriter` returns same error when trying to start. Encode process completes successfully if I'm using Documents directory and fails only when using shared app group container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're issue might be related to the use of the document folder and icloud sync.
See https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/77495#77495

If you do something like :

```
guard let containerURL = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(Constants.appGroupIdentifier) else {
        return nil
}

let libraryURL = containerURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Library", isDirectory: true)
let cachesURL = libraryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Caches", isDirectory: true)
return cachesURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("videoFile.mov")
```

Comment: getting Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}

Answer (score -1):

I can't figure out from your code where your uploadableFileURL comes from, but the following works for me:

```
if let video = videoAsset {

    let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    let url = fm[0].URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(NSDate())").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mp4")

    let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: video, presetName: AVAssetExportPreset3840x2160)
    exporter?.outputURL = url
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    exporter?.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() { _ in
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Chris, I'm setting uploadableFileURL to an app group container (shared directory between apps in an App Group, or in my case it's shared between the app and share extension). I need to use app group container since share extension does not have access to other directories (like Documents or Caches). When I use Documents or Cashes directory for an export it works, but does not for app group folder, even though I can use same uploadableFileURL for creating file manually without an error.

Comment: Hmm, and the url you are using are 'empty' so to speak? I.e. it is a newly created unique url?

Comment: Yes, I check it for file existence and remove it, and I tried to use unique name as well, so I'm sure that that file does not exist before

Comment: I've never worked with share extensions so I propably won't be of much use I'm afraid. I hope you get it sorted